# generator of first homology group of cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X = S^1 \times I$. I know that $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}$, which implies that $H_1(X)$ has 1 generator. It is intuitive to see that the generator of $H_1(X)$ is the circle that wraps around the cylinder. However, when I look at the definition of $C_1(X)$, it is the free module over the set of all continuous functions $\sigma: \triangle^1 \rightarrow X$. There are infinitely many $\sigma$,i.e,circle that wraps around $X$. So somehow, passing from $C_1(X)$ into $H_1(X)$, all of these circles become 1 equivalent class. Can anyone show me how this is true from the definition of chain complexes and homology.

Comment: consider the fundamental group of $X$

Comment: I know the fundamental group of $X$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, but the definition of chain complexes and homology do not depend on fundamental group, so I would like to see how this is derived from the definitions.

Comment: what about the homotopy properties of chain complexes and of homology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the cylinder $X= S^1\times [0,1]$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\times\{0\} = S^1$, therefore $$H_1(S^1\times[0,1]) = H_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$$

Now if you want to justify $H_1(S^1\times[0,1]) = \mathbb{Z}$ purely from the properties of the *singular* chain complex $(C_\bullet(X), \partial_\bullet)$, it's much more complicated, that's because computing singular homology groups directly from the chain complex is complicated.

Fortunately, we can equip the cylinder with a $\Delta$-complex structure. The simplicial homology $H_*^\Delta(X)$ which we get from the simplicial chain complex $(C_\bullet^\Delta(X), \partial_\bullet^\Delta)$ computes up to isomorphism singular homology $H_*(X)$.
That means, simplicial homology and singular homology are isomorphic homology theories
$$H_*^\Delta(X) \cong H_*(X).$$

Using the $\Delta$-complex structure of the cylinder allows you to directly compute the homology groups $H_n(X)$ from the respective chain groups $C_n(X)$.

The $\delta$-complex structure of the cylinder is pictured below

[$\hskip2in$ [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLC9Q.png)

Your chain groups are therefore $$C_0(X) = \langle v,w\rangle,\quad C_1(X) = \langle a,b,c,d\rangle,\quad C_2(X) = \langle A,B\rangle$$

the boundary operator $\partial_n$ is defined analougously as for the singular chain complex, therefore you can evaluate $\partial_n$ on the given generators in each degree and compute your homology groups via $$H_1(X) = \ker \partial_1/{\operatorname{im} \partial_{2}}.$$